# How do I diagnose fluorescent light flicker?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, light

We have 2x4 troffer fluorescent  lighting throughout the building. These are consistently flickering and it is annoying. Nearly every light in the building flickers, including in my room. (This includes lights on different circuit breakers.)

How shall I attribute the problem between power source, wiring, ballast or bulbs with minimum effort and wasted resources?

Comment: You mention incandescent and ballast in the same post: normally incandescent lights don't have a ballast.  Could you post model numbers for the lights?  An interior photo?  Could you plug a floor lamp into a nearby outlet and report if it flickers also?  Are there other tenants in the same building?  Does the problem go back to your meter or to elsewhere in the area?

Answer (score 1):

Flickering and buzzing where bigger problems with magnetic ballasts and cheaper type T12 Fluorescents. These are becoming obsolete, if you have these types of lamps and ballasts you can retrofit them out to the newer High Power Factor electronic ballasts and type T8 lamps, or LED tubes.

T8 fluorescent lamps are about $3.00 each and A ballast is about $17.00. LED tubes are about $8.00 a tube but you still have to retrofit the fixture.

Good luck.

Comment: Some LED retrofit 'tubes' allow you to leave the old ballast in place, making it a simple swap. Probably not the $8 ones though.

Comment: 10$ for a 20 W LED that will fit both t8 & t12 4' fixtures and are ballast compattable or direct wire 1 end or 2 end just bought a couple cases and they are great.

Comment: You are correct, I actually have a few left over from my contractor days. They're about $17.00 ea and only work with electronic ballasts. So if you have magnetic ballasts, you have to replace it then install the LED. Not exactly financially prudent.

Comment: @EdBeal - It's been a few years since we were working with them so it would be no surprise that the price went down.

Comment: Chances are you DO NOT want a plug-n-play lamp.  The old ballasts are... old... inefficient... and either already failing or about to fail.  Ballast bypass is pretty darn easy to wire up, and eliminates all ballast problems.

Comment: @Bryce I fully agree but wiring is beyond some, that's why I mentioned the last ones I got as they fit most every need. I just hope they last better than the last case of bypass or direct wire, I have had 3 out of 25 fail in less than a year they under warranty but by the time cost and hassle of shipping them back it was not worth it. The driver in each one failed but I have used the LED strips with a dc power supply in my office for fun.

Comment: @EdBeal - Yeah, I usually avoid LED questions simply because there is a lot out there and I don't fully trust them. To start if they aren't manufactured by GE, Osram, or Phillips/Sylvania, from a contractor stand point I wouldn't want to touch them. Maybe Cree but I can't even find if they are an OEM. Surprisingly, I was checking the GE lamp spec catalog and they don't have a direct wire 48" LED. They do have "plug and play" and remote drivers though.  So for my money, I would go with the tried and tested and do a fluorescent retrofit.

Comment: @EdBeal continued - I know to many this might be the ravings of some old paranoid retiree, but just remember paranoia is s survival instinct in the electrical business and I am still here.

Comment: RME, well I am here also apprenticeship completed in 79 so I have been doing this for a few weeks , also ultra high voltage work for Hewlett Packard on ion implanters 180kv. I have been converting all my t8 &t12 lamps to LED at my current plant. Note the ones that had driver failures were Cree mfg led's they are good the driver failed.

Comment: @EdBeal - Yeah we did the same thing for some big box retailers first a T8 retro then about four years later an LED plug and play. Good conversation, but I think everyone else has lost interest. So, goodbye till next time and remember it's harder to hit a moving target and don't forget to duck.

Answer (score 0):

Open one, remove the inner tubes and pop the ballast cover off. Get the model number and list of supported tubes. **Now look at the tubes that are actually installed**. I bet you find a mismatch.

It's common for someone to upgrade you to the newer T8 tubes without bothering with the inconvenient step of changing to a T8 ballast. The minimum -effort cure is install tubes supported by the ballast. The best-savings cure is install a T8 ballast, as it will start everytime and never flicker, and save energy costs too.

Now are the tubes a good match but the ballast is bulky and heavy? That is an old magnetic ballast which is failing.  Upgrade ballasts.

Does the tube have a black ring near the end of the tube? Worn-out tube.  Get new tubes with a CRI of 90+, you won't believe how nice the light looks.

Now if you change ballasts, STOP.  Shoot photos of the old ballast and the end wiring and ask a question here.  We will tell you how to select a ballast or LED replacement that will install hassle-free.  It's very easy to buy the wrong ballast and end up with a complicated mess!